# Use of selected_real_kind in Fortran to achieve desired minimum precision

Tags: gfortran

I am using gfortran 4.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.8 to compile a simple program using a specific precision:

```
program simple
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: l = selected_real_kind(18,100)
  real(kind=l) :: myNum
  myNum = 0.123456789123456789
  print '(f18.12)', myNum
end program simple
```

When I compile and run I get `0.123456791043` which obviously indicates I'm not getting the precision I called for.

However if I compile with `-fdefault-real-8` I get the right answer.  Obviously, I could just move on and use the option, but I can't help wondering whether this is a bug or I am missing some justification.  Do I really have to specify my real size outside of the code itself when it seems that `selected_real_kind` intent is to allow the code to specify precision?

Comment: Note that `selected_real_kind(18,100)` selects the x87 FPU specific extended 80-bit real kind. This has two drawbacks: (1) not many other hardware platforms support 80-bit precision and (2) array operations with this kind are non-vectorisable as SSE/AVX units only support 32- and 64-bit IEEE floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry.  You have to add `_l` to the number assignment.